# pdfCrowd Failing on live site

Tags: c#, .net, pdf-generation

I currently started using pdfCrowd for my website so users can download html as pdfs. I tested locally and it worked fine however when deploying it onto a actual website if failed with the following message:

System.Exception: Error downloading file. Please try again. --->
System.Exception: Error during rendering of Document to Pdf --->
`pdfcrowd.Error`: Exception of type 'pdfcrowd.Error' was thrown.
at `pdfcrowd.HtmlToPdfClient.convertString(String text)`...

My code in .NET looks like the following:

```
pdfcrowd.HtmlToPdfClient api = new pdfcrowd.HtmlToPdfClient("xxxusernamexxx", "xxxapi-keyxxx"); 
api.setPageMargins("3mm", "3mm","3mm", "3mm");
byte[] fileData = api.convertString(htmlString);
```

Not sure if I'm using the API correctly and whether I need to wait  to the conversion for the html (which I insert as a string). Any incite would be helpful.